# Eclipselink mongoDB native query find() not working

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, eclipselink, nativequery

I am recenttly working on a JAVA project with a mongoDB database. Being so i decided to use eclipselink 2.4. Regarding queries, it allows the usual "SQL like" queries but also (supposedly) allows native mongoDB queries. I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/NoSQL) and put everything working. I am able to run a findOne() native mongoDB query (queryOne) but i am not able to run find() queries (queryAll does no work)...

1. Query queryOne = em.createNativeQuery("db.ORDER.findOne()",
   Order.class);
2. Query queryAll = em.createNativeQuery("db.ORDER.find()",
       Order.class);

I get the error when executing the query:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [EISMappedRecord(
    value => DBQuery: myTest.ORDER -> undefined)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Order )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.nullPrimaryKeyInBuildingObject(QueryException.java:912)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1149)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1549)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:411)
    at example.Test.testQuery(Test.java:171)
    at example.Test.main(Test.java:54)
```

The execution of the query with resorting to the MongoDB shell:

```
{ "_id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A5", "TOTALCOST" : 3187, "SHIPPINGADDRESS" : [     {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H7",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada",   "PROVINCE" : "ON",  "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "17 Jane St." } ], "ORDERLINES" : [  {   "DESCRIPTION" : "machine",  "COST" : 2999,  "LINENUMBER" : 1 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "shipping",     "COST" : 129,   "LINENUMBER" : 2 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "installation",     "COST" : 59,    "LINENUMBER" : 3 } ], "VERSION" : NumberLong(1), "DESCRIPTION" : "Pinball machine", "CUSTOMER__id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A4", "BILLINGADDRESS" : [   {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H7",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada",   "PROVINCE" : "ON",  "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "17 Jane St." } ] }
{ "_id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A6", "TOTALCOST" : 565, "SHIPPINGADDRESS" : [  {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H7",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada",   "PROVINCE" : "ON",  "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "17 Jane St." } ], "ORDERLINES" : [  {   "DESCRIPTION" : "machine",  "COST" : 500,   "LINENUMBER" : 1 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "balls",    "COST" : 5,     "LINENUMBER" : 2 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "shipping",     "COST" : 60,    "LINENUMBER" : 3 } ], "VERSION" : NumberLong(1), "DESCRIPTION" : "Foosball", "CUSTOMER__id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A4", "BILLINGADDRESS" : [  {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H8",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada",   "PROVINCE" : "ON",  "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "7 Bank St." } ] }
{ "_id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A8", "TOTALCOST" : 402, "SHIPPINGADDRESS" : [  {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H7",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada",   "PROVINCE" : "ON",  "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "17 Jane St." } ], "ORDERLINES" : [  {   "DESCRIPTION" : "table",    "COST" : 300,   "LINENUMBER" : 1 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "balls",    "COST" : 5,     "LINENUMBER" : 2 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "rackets",  "COST" : 15,    "LINENUMBER" : 3 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "net",  "COST" : 2,     "LINENUMBER" : 4 },     {   "DESCRIPTION" : "shipping",     "COST" : 80,    "LINENUMBER" : 5 } ], "VERSION" : NumberLong(1), "DESCRIPTION" : "Pingpong table", "CUSTOMER__id" : "5061DC17E4B0881F592675A7", "BILLINGADDRESS" : [    {   "POSTALCODE" : "L5J1H8",    "COUNTRY" : "Canada", "PROVINCE" : "ON",    "CITY" : "Ottawa",  "STREET" : "7 Bank St." } ] }
```

If you could tell me how to fix this or a little workaround i would appreciate it.

EDIT: JPQL queries can be useful, i am using some as a workaround, however, i am not currently able to query for references ids. For example, if i have an Order with a Customer reference (the order saves only the id of the customer) with mongoDB queries i would search like taht:

```
db.ORDER.find({"CUSTOMER__id": "ID"})
```

The JPQL similar query i believe that would be like:

```
query = em.createQuery("Select o from Order o where o.customer.id = \"ID\"");
```

However, once again... not working!! Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISOneToOneMapping cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping].
Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISOneToOneMapping cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Order jpql="Select o from Order o where o.customer.id = "ID"")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1572)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1196)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1549)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:411)
    at example.Test.testQuery(Test.java:175)
    at example.Test.main(Test.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.eis.mappings.EISOneToOneMapping cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.checkForeignKeyJoinOptimization(RelationExpression.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.normalize(RelationExpression.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1365)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildNormalSelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:614)
    ... 13 more
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you fetching the results with _List orders = queryAll.getResultList();_ ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt even matter, i get the error even before that, when i run the query. I updated the question to include the error message.

Comment: Can you execute the query on prompt and post the results here?

Comment: Added the result of the shell to to the question.

Comment: Do you have @Nosql annotation (and no @Table) annotation on your entity?

Comment: Please tell me you found a solution for this.

Comment: We are not alone http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1009524/#msg_1009524

Comment: @Ernesto I simply gave up on eclipselink and used morphia...

Answer (score 0):

It appears its trying to fetch an object which has primary key as null. Moreover the records are `A5, A6 and A8.` Looks like A7 is messed up if they were created in sequence?

Would it be possible to drop the ORDER document and again run the tests (insert and get)?

Comment: The ids are okay, the A7 would be a Customer, considering the order of the persists in the code. Everytime i run the tests i drop the entire DB and create it from scratch...

Comment: I see.. doesn't look like a bug in your code. We must be missing something

Comment: Yap... I'm afraid that the find() query may not be supported, however there isn't any documentation stating that... 
Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think find() works the same as findOne() through the native MongoDB API.

What happen when you execute the native query without the class?

i.e.
Query queryAll = em.createNativeQuery("db.ORDER.find()");
queryAll.getResultList();

What do you get back?

I don't think the native find() is directly supported (but you can use JPQL for most queries).  Please log a bug for this, there should be some way to get it to work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.
When i run without the class i get a classCast excpetion (org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform) so i assume that this method is not supported for nosql.
Regarding JPQL queries, i updated the question with my problems with JPQL, if you could have a look ;)
Thanks

Comment: Please log a bug for both issues.

Comment: For the second issue, try using o.customer = :customer and pass an instance as the argument, you could also map the customerId, or define a query key.

Comment: Hi, I had to give up on JPA for this project due to these limitations... Anyway I logged a bug, just hope the next version will be better, since JPA for NoSQL would be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: I ended up doing something very nasty, I think. I created a function in mongodb that would take the cursor from find and return the concatenated ids as a csv formatted string. Then I would run a second query for the Ids. I hated it, but I had to get it out.